# How to find a parent actor in scala akka

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

I am using scala akka actor model. I have a parent actor create n child actors. Child actors first talk with each other and then report the answer to the master actor. But I could not make it work for the report part. The code structure is as follows:

```
class Master(n:Int) extends Actor{
    val system =ActorSystem("mysystem")
    for(i <- 1 to n){
        val child=system.actorOf(Props(new Node),name=i.toString) 
    }
    ... code let child actor talk with each other ...
    def receive={
        case _=>"received"
    }
}
class Node extends Actor{
    def receive={
        case => ... some code talking with each other...
                var master=context.actorSelection("../Master")
                master ! "talk back to master"
    } 
}
def main() {
    val Master=system.actorOf(Props(new Master(10)),name="Master")
}
```

Comment: This line: `  val child=system.actorOf(Props(new Node),name=i.toString) ` ought to be `  val child=context.actorOf(Props(new Node),name=i.toString)`

Answer (score 3):

Have the Master pass its self-reference to the Nodes. The relevant changed lines are:

```
... // In Master:
val child=context.actorOf(Props(new Node(self)),name=i.toString)
...
... // Definition of Node:
class Node(master: ActorRef) extends Actor{
...
//var master=context.actorSelection("../Master") - this line no longer required.
... //etc.
```

Comment: Edited - changed `system.actorOf` call to `context.actorOf`, as per comments/answer by @ViktorKlang and @Archeg. Good catch guys, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why do you create new ActorSystem? Usually it is created only once, but you already have an actor which means that you already have a system, no need to create it twice. The ActorSystem is extremely heavyweight, it allocates threads, read configuration of dispatchers, remote functionality, addresses, etc. You should never create a new one, unless you have very good reason to do that.

I'd recommend to remove creation of ActorSystem, use `context` instead of `system` when creating child actors. With that you can use `context.parent` in your `Node` to get the `Master`, because it is supervisor of all your children.

Also the query `../Master` selects a sibling rather than parent. You probably wanted `..` which results in exactly the same as `context.parent`, but `context.parent` should be faster

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
val master = context.actorSelection("/user/Master")
master ! "talk back to master"
```

You also may want to take a look at [this entry](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html#Looking_up_Actors_by_Concrete_Path) in the documentation.

Comment: Another solution would be to use the sender reference to answer Master :

    sender ! "talk back to master"

Comment: This approach is not suitable for me cuz the sender here will be the other child node instead of the master node. @christophetd